# How to make Scaffold floatingActionButton not clickable through

Tags: button, android-jetpack-compose, floating, scaffold

I have Scaffold and floatingActionButton on it.
floatingActionButton has layout as Row with fillMaxWidth and buttons on it.

Under floatingActionButton I have some buttons and I could click on empty floatingActionButton Rows place, and I could click through floatingActionButton and click on buttons which are located on the main view, under floatingActionButton.

How to make Row layout not clickable through?

```
Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
floatingActionButton = {
  Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 32.dp)) {
    Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .border(
                    width = 1.dp,
                    color = Color(0xFFC1C1C1),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 12.dp)
                )
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(80.dp)
                .background(
                    color = Color(LocalAppCustomResources.current.attachmentBackGround),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 12.dp)
                )
                .padding(16.dp)
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a `Surface` instead of the `Box` like this:

```
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier
        .wrapContentSize()
        .padding(start = 32.dp)
) {
    Row(
        //...
    ) {
        //...
    }
}
```